# onConfigurationChanged is not being called on language change

Tags: android

Although I added to the manifest file, for each activity,
android:configChanges="locale|layoutDirection"
the method is not being called, when I change the language inside the application.

**Code to change the langauge**

```
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        //          Configuration: a class describing all device configration information that can impact resources the apllication retrieves.
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

I know it is not called because I am printing to logcat and displaying a message and none is being executed

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig){

    printMyLogCat("in Onconfigarion changed");
    doMyToast(this, "in Onconfigarion changed");
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

public void printMyLogCat(String string) {
    Log.i(getClass().getName(), string);
}

public void doMyToast(Context context, String string){
    Toast.makeText(context, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: What is your code for handling the change? how do you know it's not being called?

Comment: How are you changing the language?